# QML : How to change the user-agent of a request in WebView element

Tags: webview, qml, qwebview

Is it possible to change the default **user agent** in a HTTP request that will be sent by a WebView element in QML to ,for example 'chrome....' or something else? In **QWebView** class you can re-implement ***userAgentForUrl*** virtual function. but I'm not sure that it would be possible. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass `QNetworkAccessManager` to create requests with proper headers.

Custom Network Access Manager can be registered with `QDeclarativeEngine::setNetworkAccessManagerFactory()`

Edit:

Note, in QtQuick API it's `QDeclarativeEngine::setNetworkAccessManagerFactory`, but in Qt5/QtQuick2 it's `QQmlEngine::setNetworkAccessManagerFactory`.

See [C++ Extensions: Network Access Manager Factory Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-networkaccessmanagerfactory-example.html)

Comment: Quick note: the link in your answer is unfortunately broken :(

Comment: This seems not to work. CustomQQmlNetworkAccessManagerFactory::create was never called